# Prevent Workbook_BeforeClose Event when Opening/Closing Workbook via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a _BeforeClose event, which works fine. When the user updates items manually on the workbook, and closes it, the event launches a message box and also an IE webpage to prompt the user to update corresponding items on a SharePoint list. No issues there.

However I'm also accessing the file via an add-in. The add-in takes input via a UserForm and then writes the results to the workbook with the _BeforeClose event (via standard Workbook.Open, Workbook.Range.Value, and Workbook.Close methods). In these scenarios, I don't want the event to launch the IE page or the MsgBox.

I tried to do this with a global Boolean flag in the add-in's project, reference the add-in project in the workbook of interest, and check the flag during the event. However the variable is always Empty during the event call, so I must not be setting up the global relationship correctly. (Additionally I'd prefer to do this without referencing another project anyway, if possible.)

Any ideas? Here's the relevant code:

Add-in Project:

```
Public bCallingFromProcedure As Boolean

Private Sub buttonUpdateEntry_Click() 'code runs when UserForm 'Update' is clicked

    'code that reads values of UserForm controls

    bCallingFromProcedure = True
    Dim inputBook As Workbook: Set inputBook = Workbooks.Open("path\Workbook With Event.xlsm")

    ' code that writes to Workbook With Event

    inputBook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    bCallingFromProcedure = False

End Sub
```

Workbook with Event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If bCallingFromProcedure Then
        Exit Sub ' don't load the IE page if this file is open from a calling procedure (i.e. only load when manually closing)
    End If

' code continues for launching IE page

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the `Close` call, turn it back on afterward.

Comment: Set `Cancel = True`

Comment: @Comintern Perfect, exactly what was needed. Thank you! I need to find a good resource on Application methods because I think there's probably a lot of things I am doing the hard way. Feel free to answer the question so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: @JohnyL I don't think this would work; won't that prevent the workbook from closing, instead of preventing the code in event from running altogether? I want the workbook to close all the time, but the code in the event to only run sometimes.